# localStorage.setitem do not store the object which has key that own values of arrays;

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

localStorage.setItem is storing object values incorrectly when an object has the key with array values.

```
var obj = data : { cachedat : ['1' , 2 , 3] };
localStorage.setItem('data' , JSON.stringify(obj) );
```

but

```
 var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) ; 
return like arr = data " { cachedat : []};
```

Comment: `obj = data : ` should throw error.

Comment: `localStorage` not localStorag and `{data : { cachedat : ['1' , 2 , 3] }}` not `data : { cachedat : ['1' , 2 , 3] }`

Answer (score 3):

Your code must be :

```
var obj = {'data' : { 'cachedat' : ['1' , 2 , 3] }}
localStorage.setItem('data' , JSON.stringify(obj) );
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass an object to JSON.stringify:

```
var obj = {data: { cachedat : ['1' , 2 , 3] }};
localStorage.setItem('data' , JSON.stringify(obj) );

var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var obj = {
  data: { cachedat:[1 , 2 , 3] }
};

localStorage.setItem('data' , JSON.stringify(obj));

var output = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')); 
console.log(output);
```

**Output of the above code:**

```
{
  data: {
    cachedat: [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

Comment: i just tried like this before . but i ouput would be like =>  data : cachedat : [ ] ;

Comment: @thantzintun so what output you required?, please clarify your question, also add the sample output to your question, which is required.

Comment: output should be like = {data : {cacheda : [ 1 , 2 , 3]}};

Comment: but output i got is  {data : {cacheda : [  ]}}

Comment: this output of my answer is exactly what you want. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/q1eap329/